# gem yank fails "The version does not exist"

Tags: rubygems

I'm trying to replace a bad version of my gem on rubygems.com, but yanking fails.
You can see at https://rubygems.org/gems/v2gpti that the gem does exist at v0.2. Why is this yank failing?

```
 ~ $ sudo gem yank v2gpti -v0.2
Yanking gem from https://rubygems.org...
The version 0.2 does not exist.
 ~ $
```

Comment: Just a typo: 0.2 != 2.0

Comment: I fixed the typo.  The yank still fails.

Comment: I’m not sure, but perhaps you need to specify the platform. Try `gem yank v2gpti -v0.2 -​-platform universal-darwin-13`. http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-yank

Comment: That worked.  Can you put this into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specified a platform for the gem, you also need to specify it when yanking:

```
$ gem yank v2gpti -v0.2 -​-platform universal-darwin-13
```

See http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-yank.